# Error: Network Error on old android versions in React Native with Axios

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I'm using Axios library to fetch data in a react native application. For newer android versions it's working fine. (Checked on android 11 / 13). But for older versions (checked on android 5 / 6) it gives `[Error: Network Error].`

It's an https request too.

tried by adding `uses-permission`

```
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" 
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` Still not working.

Any solutions?